# BI Engine mode is partial and the reason is due to internal errror

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-bi-engine

I created a reservation for BI Engine to make the reports on Google datastudio load faster.

I create a query and save it as view. I looked at the job information and it says "unable to support input table due to an internal error". What does it mean?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

One of your tables is defined as external table (references a spreadsheet). Unfortunately BI Engine only supports tables that are stored in BigQuery natively today. We will work on improving the error message in this case. Supporting external tables was not on our roadmap so far, unfortunately.

To get full BI Engine acceleration, please load the data from spreadsheet into BigQuery.

See BI Engine overview here: https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/introduction

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Yes. I figured this was the issue.

Comment: Also, can you clarify why on my datastudio report its not accelerated by bi engine, but on Bigquery it says "Biengine Mode: Full"

Comment: Sorry it's somewhat confusing right now. This will improve some time next year. What happens behind the scenes: there are 2 engines that will try to accelerate your query. The first is powering DataStudio. If it fails to accelerate, then query goes into BigQuery, which also has acceleration layer. This BigQuery-internal acceleration is "SQL Interface Preview" you could see in public docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/sql-interface-overview. The latter engine is distributed and supports more queries, so it will be used more often than DataStudio.